# SQL Server - Read first row and delete

Tags: .net, sql-server, stack

I'm looking to use a cloud database system as you would a stack in  .net.

There will be multiple users adding records (push) then a few applications working on loops that will read the first  record (pop) and delete it before the next Select from another machine.

The loops will be quick as there's not to do with the results, so I am concerned that one application may try and read at the same time as another.

Is this something SQL Server will handle, or do I need to manually lock?

Also any other suggestions for a multi user network stack would be great.

Comment: lookup locking hints : holdlock, readpast

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly quick response. Thanks SO again!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without database, go for any queue ( MSMQ for instance  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx )

you will also get:

- load balance ( reading will be distributed among readers )
- event driven reading (no need to query database with all
  readers)

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I needed by the looks of it. Should have asked days ago instead of head butting walls!

Comment: @RichardHarrison you should have tried to solve the actual problem (queueing stuff) instead of getting stuck on a specific implementation. This is even called [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This can make findind an answer much harder

Comment: @k010mb0 there is no MSMQ in a cloud environment, although all cloud providers have a managed queue implementation eg. Azure Queues, Amazon SQS

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the pointer. So my question should have been. How to create a networked queue system.

Comment: You did mention cloud, so just check what your cloud provider has - Azure Queues or Amazon SQS?